# XGetWindowAttributes doesn't return a correct window location

Tags: x11, xlib

I have implemented a basic x11 window application. After moving a window using mouse `XGetWindowAttributes` always returns the same window location (`x` and `y` from `XWindowAttributes` struct). Calling `XSync(display, False);` before `XGetWindowAttributes` doesn't help. Why does `XGetWindowAttributes` always return an initial window position ?

Comment: Maybe you'll need to translate position to screen `XTranslateCoordinates`.
`XWindowAttributes att; memset(&att, 0, sizeof(att)); XGetWindowAttributes(display, window, &att); Window child; XTranslateCoordinates(display, att.root, window, 0, 0, &att.x, &att.y, &child);`